# Pyspark can't run with Sublime text 3 but can run in terminal

Tags: python, pyspark, sublimetext3

I have a Pyspark program which can perfectly run in terminal. But when I tried to use sublime text 3 to build this program. It shows following error:

```
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sprout G2 Demo\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "FaceMatch")
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.py", line 316, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 46, in launch_gateway
    return _launch_gateway(conf)
  File "C:\Spark\spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 108, in _launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

OS is Windows 10, Java is JDK 8, Python is 3.7

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run a program named `cmd` and it's not being found; is that program name correct? If so, my guess would be that Sublime isn't using the same `PATH` as the terminal.

Comment: I can run other python scripts with "cmd" and everything goes well even the program uses something in PATH. This only happens when I tried to use pyspark.

Comment: What I mean is that it looks like you are literally trying to run a program named `cmd`; is that actually the name of the program that you're trying to run, or is that the name of the configuration option that specifies *what* program to run?

Comment: cmd is just command lines in windows. That's how sublime-builder works.

Comment: Is `sublime-builder` a package that you're using to build things?

Comment: My bad, it should be sublime-build. I just using anaconda environment and wrote a sublime-build file.

Comment: did you try `cmd.exe`?

Comment: cmd.exe doesn't work even for other python scripts which work before

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself. Because I created my own sublime-build file. And I add a path variable into it. This means it won't use the path variable in the system environment variables.

I changed my sublime-build file from

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"path":"C:/Anaconda3",
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"shell": true
}
```

to

```
{
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"path":"$path:C:/Anaconda3",
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"shell": true
}
```

Comment: hey, i am not able to start a pyspark shell on terminal, i have set the paths and all but didnt work. Error : The system cannot find the path specified.